# Server data accessing from non local network without port forwarding

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, xampp, client-server

I'm using XAMPP server and I have my files in htdocs folder of XAMPP.

I had connected to my laptop using my mobile hotspot.

Can I access my files in XAMPP folder from another system which is not in same network i.e., can I access the files present in XAMPP folder from another another computer via internet
without router only by mobile hotspot?

Comment: possibly you could if your hotspot allows inbound connections and/or has a configurable firewall, and allows port forwarding. The hotspot is, after all, just another type of router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to access the web server from an external network, depending on your current network configuration.

There are two simple solutions I think would suit you.

1. Configure your firewall if needed, enable port forwarding in your router settings to forward port 80 to the internal IP of the machine running your XAMPP-server.
2. If you're on a network in which you can't configure, I recommend checking out [ngrok.com](https://ngrok.com/), which is a service where you can setup a public URL for your XAMPP-server. Works from any type of network, where you have internet-access, of course.

Note, alternative 2 is good for exposing a development-server, nothing I'd recommend for running a site in production.

Answer (score 0):

Most network providers don't allow accessing the termials in the network. 
If your provider does portforwarding and entering the public(!) IP of your hotspot should bei enough.