# My Android App not working behind college proxy?

Tags: android, node.js

I have created an android app but it is not working behind the college proxy. My backend is in `socketio` and my server is in `nodejs`.

Comment: Hi, is your backend running on the same network as your Android-device? Depending on the network-setup it might be do-able, however, I'd like to recommend a service I'm using to expose my local server to a public accessible domain.

https://ngrok.com/

Comment: I hope this helps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53391368/server-data-accessing-from-non-local-network-without-port-forwarding/53392433#53392433

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Server data accessing from non local network without port forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53391368/server-data-accessing-from-non-local-network-without-port-forwarding)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change proxy settings in Android (especially in Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21068905/how-to-change-proxy-settings-in-android-especially-in-chrome)